# Umbraco 7+ Search

Tags: search, razor, umbraco, examine

I wonder if someone could help me... I am trying to get the Examine search working in Umbraco 7.3 but am struggling with the documentation.

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Searching/Examine/quick-start

when I look at the following files ExamineSettings.config and ExamineIndex.config they seem to already have the ExternalIndexer, ExternalSearcher and ExternalIndexSet already specified. I guess this is an enhancement from 4.11 which the document seems to have been written for.

But it is the section after where I seem to get lost... Is the Razor section for a Partial View? And what does the full code need to be?

I would assume if it is a partial view I would create a page to include the partial view @(Html.Partial("searcher"))

and if I viewed the page and appended a query string ~/?query=keyword this would work?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Config/ExamineIndex.config, you create a new IndexSet with all the properties you want users to be able to search for.

The Umbraco.TypedSearch(Request.QueryString["query"]); will search for anything throughout the page, but if you set up UmbracoExamine correctly, you can choose what Document Types you want people to be able to search for, as well as you can choose what kind of properties you want people to be able to index the content based on.

For example:

```
<IndexSet SetName="ExternalTopLevelSearchSet" IndexPath="~/App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes/{machinename}/TopLevelSearch/">
    <IndexAttributeFields>
      <add Name="Name"/>
      <add Name="bodyText"/>
      <add Name="tags"/>
      <add Name="themes"/>
      <add Name="parentID"/>
    </IndexAttributeFields>
    <IncludeNodeTypes>
      <add Name="ArticlePage" />
    </IncludeNodeTypes>
  </IndexSet>
```

Then you have to create an Indexer in Config/ExamineSettings.config

```
  <add name="ExternalTopLevelIndexer" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoContentIndexer, UmbracoExamine"
        supportUnpublished="false"
        supportProtected="false"
        interval="10"
        analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
        indexSet="ExternalTopLevelSearchSet"/>
```

Now, you create a Search Provider, also in Config/ExamineSettings.config

```
<add name="ExternalTopLevelSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
           analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer, Lucene.Net" indexSet="ExternalTopLevelSearchSet" enableLeadingWildcards="true"/>
```

Here's my C# code using the "ExternalTopLevel"-searcher shown above.

```
public List<SearchResult> SearchResults
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["q"])) {
                    var searcher = ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["ExternalTopLevelSearcher"];
                    // Search criteria.
                    var searchCriteria = searcher.CreateSearchCriteria(BooleanOperation.Or);
                    var q = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["q"].ToLower().Trim().Split(' ');
                    var contentType = HelperClass.GetContentTypeNodes().FirstOrDefault(item => q.Contains(item.Name.ToLower()));
                    q = q.Where(i => i.Length > 3).ToArray();
                    var query = searchCriteria
                        .GroupedOr(new[] { "nodeName" }, q.Select(x => x.Boost(150)).ToArray())
                        .Or()
                        .GroupedOr(new[] { "grid" }, q.Select(x => x.Boost(80)).ToArray())
                        .Or()
                        .GroupedOr(new[] { "tags", "themes", "institutions" }, q.Select(x => x.Boost(110)).ToArray());
                    // Search results
                    var searchResults = searcher.Search(query.Compile()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Score);
                    return searchResults.ToList();
                }
                return new List<SearchResult>();
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Do you have this in Razor by any chance?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but the code is similar. I had it in Razor and rewrote it to fit the architecture I use.

Comment: @Mikkel, I'm also new to learning this approach. If you are not using razor in this example, are you simply saving this as a class file and it just...compiles onto the page? Thanks

Comment: @blackhawk - yes, that's one way to do it. The example above is from a larger Umbraco project I did a while back where the "SearchResults"-property was part of a ViewModel or a Model

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a partial view macro from inside Umbraco and select a Search snippet that will work. You can then do @Html.RenderMacro("alias") in your template file.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this - What is the difference between a partial view and a partial view macro? I have found another tutorial but it doesn t seem to work properly but it has enable me to get a bit closer.

Comment: Nothing much is different, I think. They reside in different folders inside /Views/, but most importantly, partial view macro files can be used for creating actual macros inside Umbraco :-)